# COUNT() function each time, or store the value and increment it by one?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, record-count

I have a database with a user 'votes' table and a 'user' table. I'm thinking the database will get quite big in a small amount of time so i want to use the most efficient method.

I'm thinking i can either COUNT() the amount of votes with a WHERE statement from the 'votes' table every time, or i can store the score in the 'user' table and just increment it by 1 every time a vote is added.

Which would be best/quickest, and/or are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking of the best way to do it. You have to look into optimizing and caching a lot.

I would say, 
*Create a column on the user tables to store cached score, but maintain the score on the separate table.*

Whenever score changes operate of scores table and trigger an update on user's table with the latest score result.

Doing this, you have extendability in your score data to, kind of like what stackoverflow uses for votes.

Comment: "_Create a column on the user tables to store cached score_" Do you mean that the DB engine will store it and not the programmer?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER, I am sorry, but I dont understand you implication by the term `not a the programmer`

Answer (score 2):

In proper configuration (default configuration is good enough in most cases) MySQL 5.0+ server is caching SUM,COUNT queries, so MySQL is handling that sort of queries automatically.

But if you are using older version (MySQL 4 or less) i recommend to store COUNT(*) values in database, beacause it really cause on perfomance on bigger tables.

**Edit:** Best practice i discovered is making an COUNT(*) query every time user is adding/deleting vote/comment etc. Modern SQL servers are handling group queries very well, so we don't have to bother about perfomance.

Comment: Is there any danger of wrong results if COUNT changes so much?

Comment: IMO Best practice is make an COUNT(*) query every time user is adding/deleting vote/comment etc. Anyways modern SQL servers are handling group queries very well.

Comment: "MySQL 5.0+ server is caching SUM,COUNT queries, so MySQL is handling that sort of queries automatically." --- what your assumption is based on? To cache or not - depends on **a lot** of criterias

Comment: @zerkms I have to agree. But AFAIK caching is enabled by default.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski: 1) it is not 2) caching has nothing special with `COUNT()` or `SUM()`, it is a general mechanism

Comment: @zerkms "1) it is not" really? that's strange, i had to deal with 32M rows table last days and AFAIK only first COUNT(*) take some time. If i am wrong, please tell me.

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski: it depends on what you have done. By having only `COUNT(*)` it is impossible to say why the query was slow or fast

Comment: @zerkms just simple query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxx WHERE yyy=3`, where `yyy` is an index. And i am pretty sure Mysql 5+ (with default/proper configuration) is handling that sort of query very very well, so there is no need to cache it etc. by ourselfs. But truth is i am saying it depending on my experience isntead of mysql docs (caching), so i can agreed we need true Mysql admin here to answer the question :]

Comment: @Peter Szymkowski: If you select a list of entities each of which has some counter cached - then the overhead is 0, for your solution you need to perform additional N queries or 1 query with `GROUP BY`. PS: I will repeat again - mysql caching has nothing special to do with `COUNT(*)`, it is generic behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Precalculation is one of the often denormalizing optimizations.

So just create the precalculated column and maintain it with triggers or your application code.

As @Bohemian pointed out: you need to do that **only** if you have performance issues.

Comment: +! This is what I'd do, but only if performance became a problem. Optimize last - get it working first.

Comment: @Bohemian: that is what I assumed in the background :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a trade-off in cost and complexity. By maintaining the count in the user table, it adds some complexity to keep it accurate, and it adds cost to inserting/deleting votes. It means that adding a vote then requires (at least) updating two tables.

So it depends a little on which piece needs to be the most efficient.  If retrieving the vote count is performed an extremely large number of times, then perhaps it makes sense to maintain the count.

In my opinion, though, it would be better to go with the simpler implementation first and assume that the database will be able to optimize the query and make it a non-issue. If that turns out not to be fast enough, then make the changes to add the pre-computed count later.